# Chef mysql version 5.7 cookbook can't login as root

Tags: mysql, vagrant, chef-infra, ubuntu-16.04, chef-recipe

I'm using the chef cookbook for mysql found at
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mysql

Under a vagrant running ubuntu-16.04 
My recipe contains the block:

```
mysql_service 'foo' do
  port '3306'
  version '5.7'
  initial_root_password 'hello'
  action [:create, :start]
end
```

It installs just fine, but when I shell into my vagrant and try

```
mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -phello
```

I get an access denied message.  Is anyone else experiencing this issue?  Is this a bug in the recipe, and is there a patch somewhere that fixes it?

Comment: try with mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a strange conflict when installing that Apache and OpenSSL cookbooks in addition to MySQL.  I have not determined the exact cause, but on rebuilding the cookbook bit by bit, starting with the database server, this appears to have been the case.